# Why css styles behave that way?

Tags: html, css, angular

I created small app using angular-cli based on 'Getting Started with Reactive Programming Using RxJS by Scott Allen' on Pluralsight. It creates Observable stream of events from mouse. Nothing fancy - stream of data works nice. The only problem is that styles are applied in a weird way for me. They update div only 2 times in an unknown way. 
They are changed to 0px - once for x, once for y axis, when I move a mouse in an area of circle. One time and that's it. I changed manually these attributes in Developer Tools and it works like it should. But cannot laverage this behaviour automatically.

[image: here is screenshot]

**css html**

```
#circle {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
}

<div id="circle"></div>
```

**Typescript**

```
ngOnInit() {
  let circle = document.getElementById('circle')
  let mouse = fromEvent(document, 'mousemove')
    .pipe(
      map((e: MouseEvent) => {
        return {
          x: e.clientX,
          y: e.clientY
        }
      }),
    )

  function onNext(value) {
    circle.style.left = value.x
    circle.style.top = value.y
    console.log("xy", value.x, value.y)
  }

  mouse.subscribe(
    value => onNext(value),
    e => console.log(`error: ${e}`),
    () => console.log('complete.')
  )
```

}

Comment: Can you share your code as [mcve] on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/)?

Comment: It's here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xq7abu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add 'px' to value:

```
function onNext(value) {
        console.log(circle.style.left)
        circle.style.left = value.x + 'px'
        circle.style.top = value.y + 'px'
        console.log("xy", value.x, value.y)
      }
```

and circle will change position by mouse. [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jgmxfq)

Comment: Thanks! I knew there must be small buggy thing ;)